# Magento api rest oauth not authorizing consumer

Tags: php, api, magento, rest, oauth

I'm attempting to connect to my magento api from an external server but i'm having an issue with OAuth.

I've created a consumer in the backend, assigned what it can access, authorized the consumer through oauth using terminal and it gave me my token and token secret.

My PHP is as follows;

```
<?php

$hostUrl = 'redacted';
$callbackUrl = $hostUrl."oauth_customer.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = $hostUrl."oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=".urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = $hostUrl."oauth/authorize";
$accessTokenRequestUrl = $hostUrl."oauth/token";
$apiUrl = $hostUrl."api/rest";


$consumerKey = 'redacted';
$consumerSecret = 'redacted';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);

        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        $productsList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());
        print_r($productsList);
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo "<br/>";
    print_r($e->lastResponse);
}
?>
```

When I run this php file it redirects me to the magento site and says;

AUTHORIZE APPLICATION
consumer_name requests access to your account
After authorization application will have access to you account.
Authorize | Reject

When I click "Authorize" it redirects me to a 404 within magento. If I return to the php file it will redirect me to that same "authorize application" page over and over again.

I already have the token and such so I assume that it should already be authorized.

I'm attempting to access the name of products as well as their inventory quantity so I can't simply use guest access. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi user1678025, the answer is probably yes, but have you set up the right roles etc in the Magento admin panel? It took me a while to get all the various boxes checked.

Comment: @user1678025 have u got any solution? i have trapped into same problem. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your callback URL should not be on the remote host, it should be on your application's host.

Answer (score 0):

Remove $callbackUrl row and exchange with this code:

```
$callbackUrl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```